# Ajax error handling, ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

Im opening XML-files using jquery ajax. I would like to debug an error in IE7, but currently all i get in the alert is:

```
"Error: error, [object Error]"
```

My error callback:

```
error: function (a, b, c) {
    alert('Error: ' + b + ", " + c);
}
```

My guess would be that `b` is an object that contains some info, but i cant inspect object in IE7, since it has no console. Anyone know what the object properties are? I would like to know what went wrong in the XML import :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
```

the responseText will contain a error message.

Comment: Okay, IE7 doesnt have a console though, but ill try to alert it.

Comment: Do you run native IE7, or IE9 running as IE7? Cause if you do the latter you will have a console. (Developer tools F12 by default)

Comment: Well even if they use ie7 you might aswell use ie9 and run it as ie7 to check that everything works okey, atleast for debugging purposes :)
Or just test the page in chrome or FF and check what the error message is.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that i cant reproduce their errors in ie9 running ie7-mode. So i guess this is the best way for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

> **error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)**
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
>   Ajax Event.

I guess "exception object" refers to what you would typically expect that to be in JS, so the keys to errorThrown would be `name` and `msg`.

Comment: Ok, so `b.msg` contains some relevant info i suppose?

Comment: It would be the text of the exception, and `name` would be the name.